# Notes within the Documentation Editor

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-editor

Whilst not finalised, the [latest piece](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#specificity) of CSS documentation to be written about *Specificity* in CSS uses the letters "A", "B" and "c" to refer to its different levels. To conform with this, when writing the [Calculating Selector Specificty](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/450/cascading-and-specificity/2253/calculating-selector-specificity#t=201608101110340591306) example, I too used a lowercase *c* alongside a capital *A* and *B*.

Since Documentation came out of closed Beta a couple users have edited this example to make the *c* uppercase, which I've so far [reverted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/63294) [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81943) (and then [once more](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81946) after missing an instance of *C* right at the top).

I can totally understand why someone would want to change this, but I wrote it like this in the first place for a good reason - as I'm sure did the updated documentation (most likely to avoid confusion between HTML's `<a>` and `<b>` elements). I wish I had some way of letting future editors know why it's been written like this so that they'd perhaps think twice before making the change.

I'm not going to bother changing it back again as it's such a small and insignificant thing, but I'm sure there will be a lot of Documentation cases where editors modify things unnecessarily - especially when trying to make things look prettier.

I don't know how something like this could be implemented. Possibly using Wikipedia-like citations after specific blocks of content?

Comment: I know some tags are using "Meta" topics for guidance on how to document things in the tag, as a stop-gap.

Comment: Maybe HTML comments? Though you'll have to put them into every example.